# How can I get all the element html file from a web broswer - crawl data

Tags: .net, regex, web-crawler

My idea homework is an app using c# can listen to music online (the data is from some listening music web browser)

[image: The mp3 file I want to crawl]

Here's my code:

```
var url = "http://keeng.vn/album/cho-anh-em-nhe-khanh-phong/osYbZ3ph.html";                
var web = new HtmlWeb();              
var doc = web.Load(url);
```

After running this code, I took the value of doc and paste it outside, but on the outside, there's nothing

[image: result and I paste it out regex]

Can anyone help me with this problem, at first I thought, it's about loading javascript, so I decided to use HTML agility after googling, but it didn't work

p/s: The website allowed people to download mp3 song free from their site, or if anyone can help me with what keyword for my app to be the third-application to play from their website.

Comment: would you like to use excel vba to extract the link? btw the mp3 link doesn't exist in the source code as you showed in the picture, if you open the source code instead of inspecting you won't find the link, but you will find all the mp3s in a javascript.. so you need to crawl that javascript using regex..my regex skills is zero, so u will need someone else help in that part.